# Schedule backup for HANA Delivery Units or Calculation Views (CVs)

Tags: hana

We are using HANA 1.0 SPS12. Is it possible to schedule backup of HANA Delivery Unit or Calculation Views at some particular time?

Best Regards

Comment: HANA DUs (HANA XS classic) the object repository is stored in database tables and thus part of any database backup anyhow. The version of repository objects is also preserved and older versions can be recreated. What is the use case to back up the DUs separately?

Comment: Sorry Lars, maybe i have not understood properly. Are DUs stored in system views? If yes, then how to create copy of CVs from same. Do we need to restore  DB in order to restore delivery units? Generally when we manually export on local machines they are in .tgz format. I am looking for hdbalm command to schedule same.

Comment: The content of any DU is stored in the HANA repository tables as part of the database. What is the use case here?

Comment: We are transporting our changes from DEV environment to PROD environment thru Delivery Units. Sometimes we found that changes transported are wrong and has to be reverted back. Manually undoing huge changes is troublesome and can lead to inconsistencies. Thatswhy we wanted to have scheduled backup of DUs so that we can restore previous copy of CVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting and re-importing SAP HANA delivery units (DUs) is not an effective way to undo corrupting changes from an earlier import try.

If the rollback/uninstall function of the HANA application lifecycle management (HALM) tools are not correctly restoring the state of database object deployment from before when the DU was imported, your only chance really is to restore a database backup.

As it is generally highly recommended to take a backup before deploying to production, it should be possible to do that. 
Another important recommendation is to **not** actually deploy from DEV to PROD since this means that you're testing in the production system. Structural errors, like you mentioned in the comments, have to be identified in the TEST or QA system before even considering PROD deployment.